# How to get the number of booking for a given day?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables:

Booking (C_Name, C_Phone, B_Date, S_Time, S_Location, S_PCode, F_Location, F_PCode, Ach, Driver_ID_FK)

C_NAME: customer name

C_Phone: customer phone number

B_Date date of booking

S_Time: booking start time

S_Location: booking start location

S_PCode: start postcode

F_Location: booking finish location

F_PCode: finish postcode

Ach: achieved

Driver_ID_FK: assigned driver

Driver (Driver_ID, Driver_Name, Driver_Phone)

Issue (BookID, B_Date_FK, QTY)

Desired output:

B_DATE                           16-04-2018
Number of bookings        5

etc

How do I write a query ? please help me

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b_date, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   booking 
GROUP  BY b_date;
```